# Migrations in DJango

Tags: python, django, migration, makemigrations

I am having DJango migrations problem while making migration following error is coming.

[image]

[image]

[image]

When I run my applications using python manage.py runserver it shows this :-

[image]

However, running python manage.py makemigrations shows no changes detected
And Above three images are result after running python manage.py migrate.
What is the problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the *table> already exists Error happens, it is usually due to deleting and rerunning the initial migration or models.py file. For these scenarios,

```
python manage.py makemigrations <app_name>
python manage.py migrate --fake-initial <app_name>
```

Or if you want to fake only one migration file

```
python manage.py migrate <migration_file_number> --fake <app_name>
```

`--fake-initial` tells Django to mark initial migration as migrated without actually running its corresponding SQL.

[Django's migration document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-migrate-fake) may be helpful

Answer (score 0):

looks like you changed the database or migration files manually.
try to re-create the database.

1. delete the DB file
2. delete all migrations files (keep the init file)
3. run create migrations command
4. run migrate command